# ViewPager inside a custom compund view is not displayed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

I have a simple view pager and an adapter that can display images in the pager.
When I create the view pager and add it to the main layout everything works fine...
But i really want to encapsulate the ViewPager inside a compound view that will include other elements so i have subleased FrameLayout:

```
public class DatesFilterView extends FrameLayout
{

    private final static String TAG = "DatesListFragment";
    ViewPager mPager;

    public DatesFilterView(Context context) {this(context, null, 0);}

    public DatesFilterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {this(context, attrs);}

    public DatesFilterView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPager = new ViewPager(context);



        int imageArray[] = { R.drawable.tab_active_dates, R.drawable.tab_active_events, R.drawable.tab_active_friends, R.drawable.tab_active_location };
        ImageArrayPageAdapter adapter = new ImageArrayPageAdapter(context, imageArray);
        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        this.addView(mPager,0);
        this.requestLayout();

        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("Custom View is attached");

        this.addView(tv,1);

    }
...
```

so the text view shows fine but the view pager displays no images at all ...

The same code in the main activity will actually display the pager correctly...

```
mPager = new ViewPager(context);
int imageArray[] = { R.drawable.tab_active_dates, R.drawable.tab_active_events, R.drawable.tab_active_friends, R.drawable.tab_active_location };
ImageArrayPageAdapter adapter = new ImageArrayPageAdapter(context, imageArray);
mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

so I have isolated the behavior to having a pager nested inside a compound view ...

Am i forgetting something ?

**EDIT 1:**
I have added the following to the page adapter:

```
public int getItemPosition (Object object) { return POSITION_NONE; }
```

Now the first page is empty and is displayed only after moving to the next page and then back again .. :-\

Comment: Did you override methods like `onMeasure` or `onLayout` in the custom control?

Comment: I think you miss the LayoutParams for ViewPager. Try to use this.addView(mPager,new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Comment: Thanks.. @hieuxit I have tried to specifically define Layout params but no luck there (The default is match parent for FrameLayout so it will have no affect)

Comment: @Luksprog I did not and i have made sure that no one did in the entire hierarchy ...

Comment: @Mortalus Have you found solution for this?

Comment: Its been 6 years .. i hope i did find a solution.. but i dont remember :) .. let me see if i can review source control